# npm scripts to run packages global or local

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json

You can think that I will install nodemon with below script:

```
npm install --save-dev nodemon@1.0.0
```

So it will install the nodemon package to my project locally.(not global)

I will also add the npm script:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "nodemonscript": "nodemon yourscript.js"
  }
}
```

So if I execute **"npm run nodemonscript"** it will run the nodemon from my project local node_modules.(not global)

So somehow I will decide to also install nodemon 2.0.0 globally.

I will run this script to install package:

```
npm install -g nodemon@2.0.0
```

Finally I have nodemon@1.0.0 from my local project and nodemon@2.0.0 globally.

So if I execute

```
"npm run nodemonscript"
```

again from my local project root which have below script:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "nodemonscript": "nodemon yourscript.js"
  }
}
```

Here are my questions:

1)Which version will be execute 1.0.0 or 2.0.0?

2)I want to use always local nodemon package. Which way is more safe?

3)Are all the npm packages have the same behaviour for npm scripts?

4)And my last question is how **npx** will behaviour for this situation?

Comment: Why do you need nodemon installed globally at all? Ever since `npx` became a standard tool in the Node toolbox, there hasn't really been a good reason to install _anything_ globally anymore.